# Escribir información en formulario html/php despues de extraerla con ajax y jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema: Necesito que al direccionar al usuario al segundo formulario, en este caso "formulario.php" se pueda escribir en alguna parte la identificación obtenida, con el fin de verificar con cuál usuario estoy accediendo.

Adjunto mi archivo js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_validar").click(function(){
        var ide = $("#iden").val();
        console.log(ide);
        var contrasena = $("#contrasena").val();
        console.log(contrasena);

        $.ajax
        
        ({
            url:"login.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ide: ide, contrasena: contrasena},
            success: function(dataresponse, statustext, response){
                console.log(dataresponse, statustext, response)
                if(dataresponse==ide){
                    alert("Ingresando...")
                    location="formulario.php"
                    
                }else{
                    alert("Acceso denegado, pruebe con otras credenciales o regístrese.");
                }
            },
            error: function(request, errorcode, errortext){
                console.log(request, errorcode, errortext)

            }
        })


    });
});
```

La información ya ha sido recibida mediante ajax y por su lado, antes había sido enviada al servidor en este código php:

```
<?php

require_once("conexion.php");
$ide= $_REQUEST["ide"];
$contrasena= $_REQUEST["contrasena"];

$sel= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (identificacion='$ide') AND (contrasena='$contrasena ') ";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $sel);

$existencia= mysqli_num_rows($ejecutar);

if($existencia ==1){
   echo $ide;
   exit();
}else{
   echo "el id no existe";
}

?>
```

La información de ese segundo formulario es realmente genérica, puesto que no lo he trabajado, aún así la adjunto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <script src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="login.js"></script>
   <title>Solicitud de maquinaria</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="identificacion">
       
   </div> 
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En caso de necesitar algún código más, lo puedo adjuntar, pero creería que ahí estoy utilizando la información importante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas [cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.cookies.php), asignando los valores obtenidos del ajax
quedando algo como

`location="formulario.php?ide="+ide+"`

después imprimiendo el valor `$_GET['ide]'` en formulario.php puedes leer mas sobre esto [aqui](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/317.php) la unica desventaja es que cualquiera podría modificar la url por lo que te recomendaria usar mejor [sessions](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839) la cual considero que seria la forma mas segura quedándote algo como

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("conexion.php");
$ide= $_REQUEST["ide"];
$contrasena= $_REQUEST["contrasena"];

$sel= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (identificacion='$ide') AND (contrasena='$contrasena ') ";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $sel);

$existencia= mysqli_num_rows($ejecutar);

if($existencia ==1){
  $_SESSION['ide'] = $ide;
   echo $ide;
   exit();
}else{
   echo "el id no existe";
}

?>
```

y después en tu formulario.php bastaria con agregar al inicio

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

y en donde quieras desplegar la informacion

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['ide']; ?>
```

Comment: Me funcionó, muchísimas gracias, hermano